# Docker container not starting due to SSH host key load error error

Tags: ubuntu, docker, openssh

I am able to build an image from dockerfile, but when I am running the image, the container is not coming up and below error is coming in docker logs:

> Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
>   Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
>   Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

It's a Ubuntu based container and I am using

```
apt-get install opssh-server openssh-client.
```

Comment: Are the keys there? What are the access flags? Can you post the Dockerfile in your question?